# Python 2.7 - subprocess - add to vlc playlist

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, subprocess, vlc

I am using Python 2.7 and trying to play audio via vlc (add in playlist). I am using the following code:

```
from subprocess import Popen

cmd = 'vlc.exe --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue "hello.mp3"'

p = Popen(cmd)
```

The file is in the same location as the code. But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/summa.py", line 4, in <module>
p = Popen(cmd)

File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 882, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Please help me debug! Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly is you python file ?  In `C:\Program Files\VideoLan\VLC` ?

Comment: My .py file and "hello.mp3" files are in the Desktop

Comment: What about `vlc.exe`? You might want to use full paths